# Detect drag with finger down

Tags: iphone, ios

I've got a Scroll View with Paging View controller. The interface looks like this:

```
@interface ScrollViewWithPagingViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    UIScrollView *scrollView;
    UIPageControl *pageControl;
    NSMutableArray *viewControllers;
}
```

and it lets me switch pages as expected when you do a swipe.

However, I'd like it to switch pages if you have one finger down and then do a swipe with a second finger which it currently doesn't do. Not quite sure how to proceed though.

- Add a UIGestureRecogniser?
- Subclass UIScrollView?

Comment: Use `touchesBegan` to check if it's a multitouch, set a `boolean`. If it is, use `touchesMoved` to check if one of the fingers (possible ONLY one?) if the fingers has moved an amount of pixels and then use `touchesEnded` to reset the `boolean`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Use touchesBegan to check if it's a multitouch, set a boolean".

Answer (score 0):

I would probably set a `UIGestureRecognizer` on the `UIScrollView`, specifically a [`UISwipeGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UISwipeGestureRecognizer). Then you would want to set the `numberOfTouchesRequired` property:

```
swipeGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
```

With any luck, this gesture will fire and allow you to cancel any other events (so that you don't scroll, or zoom, or...something else).

Answer (score 0):

Just as a hint, if I got you correctly what you are trying to do is a pinch right? Like when you zoom out on iphone. If you keep a finger down and swipe the others in some direction is IMHO a pinch. If that is the gesture you are trying to use you should look into `UIGestureRecogniser` and in particular into `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` (check http://bit.ly/f5sZMw) (developer.apple.com link).

-- Umberto

Comment: OK, tried this. So, the problem here is it works the first time but then, if you lift the second finger up and try to swipe again, no more Pinch gestures are recognized.

Comment: Ok, then you probably have to write your own gesture recognizer... You can find an example in this book http://www.apress.com/mobile/iphone-ipad/9781430230243 (if you have it). If you don't have it let me know and I can post here an example for you...